# find all $v(x,y)$ so that $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm practicing to write down solutions clearly and thoroughly. Is this a proper answer to this exercise? How can it be improved?

Let $u(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$, find all $v(x,y)$ so that $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is entire.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations tell us that:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \qquad \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

Therefore:

$$\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dy= \int \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dy = v(x,y)$$

$$\int -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dx =\int \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx= v(x,y)$$

Using that:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=3x^2-3y^2 \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-6xy$$

I find:

$$\int 3x^2-3y^2 \, dy = 3x^2y - y^3 + C_1 = v(x,y)$$

$$\int 6xy \, dx = 3x^2y + C_2 = v(x,y)$$

So:

$$3x^2y - y^3 + C_1 =  3x^2y + C_2 \Longrightarrow C_1 = w, C_2=-y^3 + w \quad w \in \mathbb{C}$$

And:

$$v(x,y)= 3x^2y - y^3 + w \quad w\in \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: Are you asking, find $v(x,y)$ such that $f(x+iy)=x^3-3xy^2+iv(x,y)$. Because if so it sounds like a differential equation to me.

Comment: do you mean I tagged it wrong?

Comment: No I'm just conjecturing it being able to be solved via differential equations. Is this the question you are asking?

Comment: I just need practice writing down the details clearly for my exams, so I'm posting it here for input. I guess you can look at it like finding the general solution to a system differential equations, but it's pretty straightforward since you can just integrate it.

Comment: Is $f(x+iy)$ analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think our OP falibali's argument is essentially correct and well-written, but could be improved slightly by the inclusion of the suggestions made in axotatje's answer.  One need always remember that, when integrating a multivariate function with respect to only *one* of its arguments, the so-called "constant of integration" will in actuality be a function of the remaining (non-integrated) variables.  And I think for the sake of clarity and communication it is often best to explicitly show these functional dependencies.  These *caveats* aside, the OP's proof looks fine.

These things being said, there are other approaches which lend themselves to clean, concise expression:

Assuming we're looking for *real* functions $v(x, y)$, here's another way to look at it:  with $z = x + iy$, recall that

$z^3 = (x + iy)^3 = x^3 - 3xy^2 + i(3x^2y - y^3), \tag{1}$

by the binomial theorem, or by just grinding it out if one pefers.

Since $z^3$ is entire (as indicated in zhw.'s answer), and the real part of $z^3$ is $x^3 - 3xy^2 = u(x, y)$, we see that $v(x, y) = 3x^2y - y^3$ is one possible solution for $v$.  Now let $w(x, y)$ be another function with $f(z) = u(x, y) + iw(x, y)$ entire. Then $z^3 - f(z)$ is also entire; but

$z^3 - f(z) = u + iv - (u + iw) = i(v - w); \tag{2}$

that is, the real part of $z^3 - f(z)$ is zero.  Then by Cauchy-Riemann applied to $z^3 - f(z)$, we see that

$\nabla (v - w) = 0; \tag{3}$

that is, $v - w$ must be constant.  Thus

$w(x, y) = v(x, y) + C = 3x^2y - y^3 + C, \;\; C \in \Bbb R; \tag{4}$

thus every requisite $v(x, y)$ is of the form

$v(x, y) = 3x^2y - y^3 + C \tag{5}$

for some real $C$.

Answer (score 1):

You should write $C_1(x)$ instead of $C_1$ and $C_2(y)$ instead of $C_2$:

$$v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3+C_1(x)=3x^2y+C_2(y)$$

Then, $C_2(y)=C_1(x)-y^3$. This implies that $C_1(x)$ is constant. Therefore,

$$v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3+C$$

for some $C\in\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$z^3 = (x+iy)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2(iy) +3x(iy)^2 +(iy)^3 = x^3  -3xy^2 +i(3x^2y-y^3).$$

Since $z^3$ is holomorphic, one answer to the problem is $v(x,y) = 3x^2-y^3.$ You still have to show any other answer has the form $v(x,y) + C$ for some real $C,$ but at least this shows where the problem comes from.